# get data from a ngrepeated div to another div on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

```
<div ng-app="appPage" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1 class="logo">Todlio</h1>
      <a href="setting.html"><i class="icon setting" style="color:#fff;font-size:1.8em;;position:absolute;top:11px;right:12px;"/></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <div class="todo_column">
        <div style="font-weight700;text-align:center; margin:20px;">
          <a href="#/add" ng-click="addTodo()" class="ui basic button">
            <i class="add square icon"></i>
            Add
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <a href="#/"><li ng-href="#/" ng-click="detail($index)" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <h3 ng-model="title">{{ todo.title }}</h3>
            <h6>{{ todo.note_date }}</h6>
          </li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="todo_full">
        <div class="todo_title" ng-scope="todo in todos">
          <span><h1>{{ title }}</h1></span>
          <span class="check">
            <i style="font-size:2em;" class="square outline icon"></i>
            <a href="#/edit"><i class="write icon" style="font-size:1.8em;"></i></a>
          </span>
        </div>

        <h4>Note:</h4>

        <p class="todo_note">{{ note }}
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Controller

```
 app.controller("appController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.todos = [
        {title: "Call Vaibhav", note: "", note_date: ""},
        {title: "Grocery", note: "Lemons, Apple and Coffee", note_date: ""},
        {title: "Website design for Stallioners", note: "UI/UX on xyz@mail.com", note_date: ""},
        {title: "Fill MCA form", note: "First search for all the colleges", note_date: "" }
      ];

  $scope.detail = function(x){
    $scope.todos.title = $scope.title;
    $scope.todos.note = $scope.note;
  };
```

I want to get the clicked list item title and the note attached to it to the different div below
Can anybody please help. Its a todo app the left half has the list to todos and the right half has a note attached to it or anything checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One easy way is as follows:

1. Define a $scope variable with a name like $scope.currentTodo.
2. In the repeat loop, the ng-click would set $scope.currentTodo=todo
3. This current variable will hold the todo object so you can use {{ $scope.currentTodo.title }} in place of {{title}}
4. Ditch the ng-scope

Comment: Thankyou so much. Rather than defining a new scope variable because it was giving me variable undefined i took the todo variable and it returned the object now everything is good